# Android.os.Build data examples, please

Tags: android

can some owners of Android devices please come forward and publish the data that their phones provide as:

- os.android.Build.BOARD
- os.android.Build.BRAND
- os.android.Build.DEVICE
- os.android.Build.DISPLAY
- os.android.Build.MODEL
- os.android.Build.PRODUCT

I'm wondering what's the best identifying combination, looking for stats. Thanks in advance.

Comment: whats the easiest way to get this data out?

Comment: I got the data from my acra crash reports (http://code.google.com/p/acra/). Cannot find a column product in there though. 
You can probably also get the data via code somehow.

Comment: `adb -d shell getprop | grep product`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I've discovered this recently: http://www.glbenchmark.com/phonedetails.jsp?benchmark=glpro11&D=Samsung+SGH-I997+Infuse+4G&testgroup=system

Just choose your device on the drop then choose tab system to view phone info

Comment: this is helpful, but they don't appear to publish the data as just a full list of device information or give you the ability to do reverse lookups (ie. given a android.os.Build.DEVICE, which phone is it from). Does anyone know of a source for this data?

Comment: FYI, I did Google site searches to do reverse lookups on their data. Not perfect, but can be helpful: 
https://www.google.com/#q=site%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.glbenchmark.com%20android.os.Build.DEVICE%09aloha - is the LG Ally
https://www.google.com/#q=site%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.glbenchmark.com%20android.os.Build.DEVICE%09passion - is the Google Nexus One
https://www.google.com/#q=site%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.glbenchmark.com%20android.os.Build.DEVICE%09pyramid - is the HTC Sensation
https://www.google.com/#q=site%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.glbenchmark.com%20android.os.Build.DEVICE%09supersonic - HTC Evo 4G

Comment: I would like to have a wiki with all phones, specicications (like the one in xda) but also with it's associated android.os data and perhaps an app to enable users to send it's  data and update the wiki.

Comment: Looks like that site was redesigned and they no longer show Build fields. Much sad.

Comment: dead link (the link now redirects to some other site not related to the question)

Answer (score 32):

**HTC Desire 2.1update1:**
Board:bravo
Brand:htc_asia_wwe
device:bravo
display:ERE27
model:HTC Desire
product: ?

**Nexus One, 2.2**
board:mahimahi
brand:google
device:passion
display:FRF50 (this is not the N1 stock version, but update I loaded onto it)
model:Nexus One
product: ?

**EDIT:**

**Samsung Galaxy S, 2.1update1**
board:GT-I9000
brand:Samsung
device:GT-I9000
display:ECLAIR
model:GT-I9000
product: ?

Comment: Why no product? Is it NULL on those?

Comment: Output was "?" as far as I remember.

Answer (score 27):

If you want to test it in the emulator or Real phone, try using this code:

```
    String  ANDROID         =   android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE;       //The current development codename, or the string "REL" if this is a release build.
    int     SDK             =   android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;       //The SDK version of the software currently running on this hardware device.

    String  BOARD           =   android.os.Build.BOARD;                 //The name of the underlying board, like "goldfish".
    String  BOOTLOADER      =   android.os.Build.BOOTLOADER;            //  The system bootloader version number.
    String  BRAND           =   android.os.Build.BRAND;                 //The brand (e.g., carrier) the software is customized for, if any.
    String  CPU_ABI         =   android.os.Build.CPU_ABI;               // [API >= 4] The name of the instruction set (CPU type + ABI convention) of native code.
    String  CPU_ABI2        =   android.os.Build.CPU_ABI2;              // [API >= 8] The name of the second instruction set (CPU type + ABI convention) of native code.
    String[]CPU_ABIS        =   android.os.Build.SUPPORTED_ABIS;        // [API >= 21] An ordered list of ABIs supported by this device.
    String  DEVICE          =   android.os.Build.DEVICE;                //The name of the industrial design.
    String  DISPLAY         =   android.os.Build.DISPLAY;               //A build ID string meant for displaying to the user
    String  FINGERPRINT     =   android.os.Build.FINGERPRINT;           //A string that uniquely identifies this build.
    String  HARDWARE        =   android.os.Build.HARDWARE;              //The name of the hardware (from the kernel command line or /proc).
    String  HOST            =   android.os.Build.HOST;
    String  ID              =   android.os.Build.ID;                    //Either a changelist number, or a label like "M4-rc20".
    String  MANUFACTURER    =   android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER;          //The manufacturer of the product/hardware.
    String  MODEL           =   android.os.Build.MODEL;                 //The end-user-visible name for the end product.
    String  PRODUCT         =   android.os.Build.PRODUCT;               //The name of the overall product.
    String  RADIO_VERSION   =   android.os.Build.getRadioVersion();     //The radio firmware version number.
    String  SERIAL_NEW      =   android.os.Build.getSerial();           // [API >= 26] Gets the hardware serial number, if available.
    String  SERIAL_OLD      =   android.os.Build.SERIAL;                /* [API >= 9] A hardware serial number, if available. Alphanumeric only, case-insensitive.
                                                                        This field is always set to Build#UNKNOWN. */
    String  TAGS            =   android.os.Build.TAGS;                  //Comma-separated tags describing the build, like "unsigned,debug".
    long    TIME            =   android.os.Build.TIME;                  //The time at which the build was produced, given in milliseconds since the UNIX epoch.
    String  TYPE            =   android.os.Build.TYPE;                  //The type of build, like "user" or "eng".
    String  USER            =   android.os.Build.USER;
```