# android.os.Build.MODEL values

Tags: android

I am looking to get all the android.os.Build.MODEL values for phones and tablets so I can customize my application to features for these specific phones. Is there an existing list out there? Could someone provide me with a list?

Comment: i see that is no easy. so i choose my targets:

Comment: what i got if i use: nexusOne, GalaxyNexus, samsung galaxy and any device tab

Comment: This answer from another question points to a site which has the values for various Android devices: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8056925/211292

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best list I could find is
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Android_devices

but sadly it does not include the android.os.Build.MODEL values :o(

Comment: yes we can use the column name in the table. but it is not true for all devices.
Thanks

Comment: it used to but some moronic wikipedian removed it because they considered it "useless"

Comment: Looks like that link has been deleted since the time you answered.

Answer (score 1):

To publish apps, you need an account at Google Play. Go to play.google.com/apps/publish and login. There at Menu APK is a list of all supported Devices. The names of the devices are similar to android.os.Build.MODEL and there you will find the android.os.Build.DEVICE parm, too.