# Where can I find all android.os.Build.MODEL value for all phone?

Tags: android, build, model, key-value

As the question stated, is there anyway I can get these values for every smartphone?

Comment: possible duplicate of [android.os.Build.MODEL values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9362903/android-os-build-model-values)

Comment: i don't understand the question. what's wrong with android.os.Build.MODEL?

Comment: i want to know the model of all smart phone, not how to display it, because I'm writing an app that check for phone support by using this MODEL value. and the answer on that link is not correct...

Answer (score 4):

You can get a very long list of device makes and models from [Google's list of Supported Devices](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/1727131?hl=en). As of March 2023, there are over 38,500 devices listed. The device list can be downloaded as a CSV file (very useful) or as PDF.

Answer (score 0):

it's not possible to list all smart phones details. By using android.os.Build.MODEL we can find which device we are using. please refer this site for smart phone details (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Android_devices)

Answer (score 0):

It's not complete, but you can try https://github.com/mataanin/android-devices

Comment: The repo is 10 years old as of year 2022